# Use CSS in Django

Tags: css, django, pyhook

I have a Django project structure like this

```
 Project
    app
    media
    static
      style.css 
    templates
      base.html
```

and in settings

```
    PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..') 
    SITE_ROOT = PROJECT_ROOT
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'static')

    STATIC_URL = '/static/'

    STATICFILES_DIRS = (
        os.path.join(SITE_ROOT,'static')
      )

     STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
        'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
         'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
     )
```

and in base.html reference to the css file :

```
  <link href="{{STATIC_URL}}/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

and it gives an error :

```
 "The STATICFILES_DIRS setting should "
 ImproperlyConfigured: The STATICFILES_DIRS setting should not contain the STATIC_ROOT setting
```

the browser shows html files in no-css style , what can be the problem?

Comment: Have you added 'django.contrib.staticfiles' to INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: yes i have it in INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: Please check the `link href` line, I have added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line should be the culprit:

```
<link href="{{STATIC_URL}}/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Remove the trailing slash after {{STATIC_URL}}

You should say

```
<link href="{{STATIC_URL}}style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Can you make sure STATICFILES_DIRS refer to your `static` directory.

```
from django.conf import settings
print settings.STATICFILES_DIRS
```

Comment: it printsout something like 'C:\\Users\\hl\\workspace\\faahjaelp\\theproject\\..\\static'
and show an error
   "The STATICFILES_DIRS setting should "
ImproperlyConfigured: The STATICFILES_DIRS setting should not contain the STATIC_ROOT setting

Comment: If you are in development mode, you can comment your `STATIC_ROOT` for now and it should be fine.

Comment: thanks it worked, but what if i have to put it in production?

Comment: Put STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'static_root'). Its only used when you use `python manage.py collectstatic` and it only tells the location where all your static files should be collected to. So, its just telling to django that collect all my static files in directory named `static_root`